# Designing a Multistage Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, design, differential, gain, input-impedance

I have to design a BJT multistage amplifier to meet a specification provided by my professor. The first stage is to be a differential amplifier, and the second stage is to be a common collector amplifier. However, the first stage won't be a differential amplifier in the traditional sense; it's to be thought of as a common collector fed into a common base. Overall it's common collector -> common base -> common collector. See the circuit below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuWpOy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitor C4 is to short out the 10k resistor at AC, so the left half of the differential amplifier acts like a common base. The power supply does not have to split, I just found it to result in a higher gain that way.

A couple other restrictions imposed on the design by my prof:

-Can only use three transistors; two for the differential stage, and one for the common collector output stage. They can be NPN or PNP.

-Achieve as much gain as possible. Aim for at least 45dB.

-For each transistor, add a 1nF capacitor from the base terminal to the collector terminal. This is to simulate the effects of high frequency while only using a frequency of 10kHz.

-Output stage is to drive a 1k load.

-Add a 10k resistor to the input of the first stage. This represents the output impedance of a previous stage.

Mainly there are two challenges: 1.) Achieving max gain out of the amplifier 2.) Making sure the gain is effective at the frequency of interest.

So essentially the things that can be altered are the Q-point currents and voltages, and the input and output impedances of each stage, which is tricky because they are not entirely independent of each other.

My understanding: Each stage should be designed to have the input impedance as large as possible, and the output impedance as small as possible in order to minimize loading effects. The two common collector stages should be designed to have gain as close to unity as possible. The common base is the "meat" of the amplifier, in that it is the only source of gain.

There must be a maximum value of obtainable gain, and there must be a way to find it. I'm just not sure where to go from here. I came up with a design that can get approximately 35dB of gain, but it was more a matter of messing around with values in SPICE, so I don't have a good explanation of why it works or how to improve it. I have a decent understanding of basic amplifiers, but was never really taught how to design. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: As drawn, there is no DC path to Q3 base. That can't be right...

Comment: @BrianDrummond, there was a mistake in the circuit that I fixed, but I still don't see what you mean. The positive and negative rails, V_CC and V_EE will supply DC to Q3.

Comment: @Lefty, before you edited it, R5 and R6 were not connected to the base of Q3. Therefore the base had no DC bias applied to it.

Comment: @mkeith, I realized that shortly after posting my response. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ask yourselves: what determines the gain ? Are you familiar with small signal representation ? Then you know about gm, it feeds a current into a load resistor, this sets the gain. Does Q3 provide any voltage gain ? How much is it ? Focus on the components and properties that are important for the gain, ignore that what is needed for biasing.

Comment: Now fixed. One question and hint : are there any constraints on the "frequency of interest" or the required bandwidth, and (given those capacitors) can you think of ways to increase impedance at those frequencies?

Comment: @BrianDrummond, the frequency of interest is 10kHz and there were no restrictions on bandwidth. I’m not sure I know what you mean by “increase impedance.” Which impedance? If you mean  that of the capacitor, the impedance (well, reactance) is inversely proportional to the capacitance. So, if we wanted to increase the impedance, we could decrease the capacitance. However, that doesn’t really make sense to me because all of the non-parasitic capacitors in the circuit act to bypass and couple things.

Comment: @FakeMoustache, yes, I am familiar with the hybrid-pi model and small signal analysis. The transconductance  gm is proportional to the collector current. So, larger gm  = larger IC, and larger IC = larger IE. Is that what you mean by “gm sets the gain.”? As far as what determines the gain, that depends on which stage you are looking at. Looking at it in stages, from left to right you have a common collector, common base, and then a common collector again. Q1 and Q3 do not provide any gain, they act as common collector amplifiers, whose gain can never be greater than unity.

Comment: @FakeMoustache, wouldn’t the main goal of those amplifiers be to achieve gain as close to unity as possible, so as to minimize attenuation? Q2 provides all the gain of the circuit. The gain of a common base amplifier depends mainly on gm and the collector resistor, R2 in the circuit. Increasing the collector resistor increases the gain, but decreases the collector current, which in turn decreases the gain. I also don’t see how you can neglect biasing, since the Q-point directly affects the gain (gm ,rπ,, and the choice of resistor values).

Comment: You can increase the impedance measured across a capacitor - at or below a specific frequency - without reducing the capacitor. It's a common technique in radio circuitry and has been used to extend the bandwidth of DC-video amplifiers.

Comment: "the main goal of those amplifiers be to achieve gain as close to unity as possible" for Q3: yes, that is correct. Q3 provides only current gain, the (signal) voltage remains the same. It lowers the output impedance. Q1 AND Q2 both determine the gain. You can only understand that after analyzing the small signal equivalent. You're right R2 is also important. I don't neglect the biasing but I see the biasing separate from the gain. First determine what you need to make the gain, then see what consequence this has on the biasing. Doing both at once is confusing and not needed.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, so that just extends the bandwidth? I'm not sure how to do that. How does that help with the gain? Getting 45dB of gain takes precedence over the bandwidth.